# How to improve the C++ code to get similar efficiency as in the Fortran code with arrays

Tags: optimization, fortran, g++

There are two codes in Fortran and C++ with simple array manipulations with different declarations of arrays for C++. Let me know how to improve C++ code to get similar efficiency as in the Fortran code. The duration of runs in seconds is summarized below.

The Fortran program:

```
! fort.f90

PARAMETER ( N=1000000, M=10000 )
REAL*8, ALLOCATABLE :: D(:)  
ALLOCATE(D(N))

A=1.0

DO J=1,M
   DO I=1,N
      D(I)=A+I+J
   ENDDO      
ENDDO      

END
```

The Cpp program:

```
// main.cpp

using namespace std;
using namespace blitz;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

int  N=1000000, M=10000;

double* D=new double[N];
//Array<double,1> D(N); // for Blitz C++
//vector<double>D(N);
//valarray<double>D(N);

const  double a=1.0;

size_t i,j;

for (j=0; j<M; j++)
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        D[i]=a+i+j;

return 0;
}
```

`g++ main.cpp -o main         && time main`

`g++ main.cpp -o main -Ofast  && time main`

`f95 fort.f90 -o fort        && time  fort`

`f95 fort.f90 -o fort -Ofast && time  fort`

Here is statistics:

1) double* D=new double[N]; g++: 58,1s, g++ -Ofast : 16,413s

2) valarrayD(N);  ~ the same

3) vector;                ~ the same

4) BlitzC++ ;               g++ :  3m19,017s, g++ -Ofast : 15,142s

5) ALLOCATE(d(N));          f95 : 42,092s, f95 -Ofast : 0,002s

Comment: The Fortran program can be optimized to the equivalent program `end` if you allow the compiler to ignore FP states (and looks like it is in one case). It could be better if you write a program which doesn't suffer that drawback. (I don't know whether the C has the same issue.)

Comment: I mean that difference is 5 orders for -O3: g++ is too slow! It is something strange.

Comment: Sorry - 4 orders

Comment: I changed to D(I)=D(I)+A+i+j. Nothing changed.

Comment: Try e.g. summing the array `D` at the end of the program and printing that value to avoid elimination of the code. Then the run times for C++ and Fortran will be very similar. With `-Ofast` I am getting 4 seconds in both cases.

Comment: jacob, thnaks! It helps. In my case: f95 -Ofast - 15,678s, and  g++ -Ofast  - 19,692s. But the final code was  D(I)=D(i)+A+I+J. So, for -O2, -O3 and -Ofast we have BUG for f95.  Because D(I) should accumulate data from the outer loop (J=1,M).

Comment: This is not a bug. You program does not use the result of the computation in any way. So the compiler is free to skip the optimization altogether.